# Converting .MCX to .XML and back again using python

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to make a program that writes these macros faster than I can type them. The macros that I'm trying to make the program for are contained in a file with the extension .MCX. I'm not sure where to start. The first thing I did was investigate what these .MCX files are. From what I learned they are some sort of compressed XML file. When I open them in my text editor I get this.

```
504b 0304 1400 0000 0800 fb72 d44e baf6
0fe7 4801 0000 e203 0000 0b00 0000 5841
4354 444f 432e 584d 4cb5 935d 4bc3 3014
86ff 4acc 85bd 90d9 4d11 44db 8ed8 a5ac
d276 b3cb 3664 8e51 bb38 025d 5bd3 ec0b
f1bf 7b5a 717e 81a8 d08b 1092 bc39 cf7b
7272 8cf6 7699 a035 9785 c852 536b 1d37
35c4 d338 9b8b 7461 6a43 e634 ce35 d4b6
0c9f d861 6faf c3a7 1881 869b 98cc c684
d170 466f 86ae dbf7 69c0 309a f322 9622
5795 1204 91e2 1279 5951 a006 a28f 2b91
2f79 aab0 65f4 aeae a9cd 0696 e1b9 019d
b98c fa48 1441 a620 6cab 8cbf 3671 67c3
9304 ac80 3a85 03c6 b7ca 320e 2676 8730
3279 ba3b b3a5 7a40 30dd a3d2 40c5 bf80
651e c96a b7f9 3c9d 5a86 fe7e 55df a33e
5263 70b8 c8e4 cec4 6316 6254 f084 c72a
9380 effa 870b 75f9 3630 8a62 25d6 4281
f208 1c46 49bc 4aa2 d73c 9b18 495e 79fe
e65d ff1d 2bbc ad35 7e97 f6c9 880c 7e62
3865 ed72 c0b0 5d0e 4538 f933 b2eb 7f42
06c4 2141 3d8f f785 e494 d9d5 4ff1 46a4
5ffb 4718 13cf fb3f 40df 7795 5ef5 acf5
0250 4b01 0200 0014 0000 0008 00fb 72d4
4eba f60f e748 0100 00e2 0300 000b 0000
0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0058
4143 5444 4f43 2e58 4d4c 504b 0506 0000
0000 0100 0100 3900 0000 7101 0000 0000
```

It looks like hex to me. But I'm very new to this so I'm not completely sure. This was a little discouraging. I did some more googling and I found this site that lets you view the file. https://filext.com/file-extension/MCX
This is when I found out that the file is some sort of compressed XML file...

```
<MACRO version="3" code="A_WATER_EQUIIPMENT" description="A_Water Loss - Equipment">
    <OBJECTS>
        <LINE_ITEM isNote="1" cov="Dwelling">
            <noteText>
                <![CDATA[ {\5Crtf \5Cb EQUIPMENT:\5Cpar \5Cb0} ]]>
            </noteText>
        </LINE_ITEM>
        <LINE_ITEM category="WTR" selector="DHM>>>" activity="+" calculation="0" recov="1" cov="Dwelling"/>
        <LINE_ITEM category="WTR" selector="DRY" activity="+" calculation="0" recov="1" cov="Dwelling"/>
        <LINE_ITEM category="WTR" selector="HEPAVAS" activity="+" calculation="F" deprecType="2" recov="1" cov="Dwelling"/>
        <LINE_ITEM category="HMR" selector="NAFAN>>" activity="+" calculation="0" recov="1" cov="Dwelling"/>
        <LINE_ITEM category="HMR" selector="FHEPA>" activity="+" calculation="0" recov="1" cov="Dwelling"/>
        <LINE_ITEM category="HMR" selector="FLVAP>" activity="+" calculation="0" recov="1" cov="Dwelling"/>
        <LINE_ITEM category="WTR" selector="WALL" activity="+" calculation="0" recov="1" cov="Dwelling"/>
    </OBJECTS>
</MACRO>
```

So here's where I've stuck the program that uses this .MCX file doesn't like when I just uploading an XML file. It has to be the compressed version. I don't exactly know how that website converted it. I did some more googling I played with the website. I'm completely lost on what to do next. The only hint I found was this. In between Hex(I think) to XML the website printed out this.

```
PK  ûrÔNºöçH â  XACTDOC.XMLµ“]KÃ0†ÿJÌ…½ÙMDÛŽØ¥¬Òv³Ë6dŽQ»8][Óìñ¿{Zq~¨Ð‹’¼9Ï{rrŒöv™ 5—…ÈRSk75ÄÓ8›‹tajCæ4Î5Ô¶,¿øÏãÇ8¡¦»¸ìæ¤ñf¦Îûė‰àPºēB¶Bwµ2$±Ă2™yqÀ&Â¯K±O™ÊÐ…ĔÎÎÉí&¶āÙ!½Ù¬Ěh4aÆ@ŒË¬ßV‘‡ã³$Ì Z¥#æ×êR.F–§PR™Ú[ÓÅš`PýÃò`åß …>éŠ×ę\½z¦ĞžuÿÃ^rƒØèĄîäƒ6‚tĐ¤çJ³ ďĚ§+•ęVPª‚Eöb¡Ē(<fiÜjÂ÷\»8i~™ĞĆ}ğ=KÜÍUž·Ėé¨,ž‚X…č’àÐ}.eXęSÒċŸb&äAa]¯ė¥Ą´ùõođfÄěg83ïě_`ÿ—µ~ĕÌĕ"pk!" 4 ( ě’ônÚĖ/ćh! Ă# + ! xactdocNxmlpk%& ! ! Y ‘!
```

My Question is. Is the first example Hex? If so is there a way to convert Hex to XML or XML to Hex? What is the 3rd example mean? Where is a good place to learn more?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

After reading the comments I Used 7zip to see if the file would unzip. I got an Error but then I renamed the file to .zip and it worked the file contained the .xml file! Thank you Jim!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c05M5.jpg)

Comment: What is a .mcx file _supposed_ to contain?

Comment: The `PK` header bytes designate a zip file, and appear in both the hex dump and the text version.  You can verify this by running an unzip program on the file to list its contents. Then all you have to do is create a zip file containing the macros you want.

Comment: The .mcx file is supposed to contain macros from my understanding the .mcx extension is a compressed version on a xml file. The macros are organized with the xml file and are then compressed into this .mcx file.

Comment: Get an unzip utility of your choice.  Run it with the "list" option (whatever that is on your unzip program). Feed it the .mcx file as its zipped input.  [Edit] your post and include the output.

Comment: Thank you Jim! I renamed the file as a .zip file and it contained the xml file!